# Create Custom Context menu

Tags: android, custom-contextmenu

I want to create a custom context menu . can any one provide me a good example ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide custom layout and use AlertBuilder to show popup instead of default context menu. Inflating your custom layout on systems will give you custom context menu.

HTH